# Marmalade User Interface on Mac OS X

Tags: user-interface, airplay, marmalade

I realized that there is no Mac OS UI builder.
Can you please tell the best way to create a user interface on Mac OS?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you programming in? Interface builder in built into XCode, which is free.

Answer (score 0):

The 'official' [GUI builder tool](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/docs#/tools/uibuilder/uibuilderoverview.html) (beta) doesn't appear to run on os x so I think you have no choice but to create the application gui by hand-editing the xml definitions. I cant find any reference to a third-party tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "Mac OS UI builder", but as far as I understand Xcode comes with a tool to build interfaces graphically. It is called ["Interface Builder"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder), and it is integrated in Xcode 4. You can find many tutorials about it on the web.

[Here a tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-iphone-application-with-interface-builder) focusing on the iPhone.

Comment: I mean developing on marmalade SDK ex airplay

Answer (score 0):

Ive been using vmware fusion to launch the PC version.   Not ideal i know, but better than editing by hand.  The next point release of Marmalade however is promising a big change in UI building (I predict it will use JS/web view :) ) so i wouldn't expect a UI builder soon if theres a new system coming.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged with Marmalade, I can tell you that Marmalade SDK comes with a great UI builder tool for creating .ui files, which you can compare with .xml files for Android or .xib file for iOS.

Comment: ...except unfortunately it doesn't any more.  The Mac version of Marmalade has never had a UI builder tool and it has now been shelved in the PC version too (as of v6.0.3 and possibly earlier).  Apparently the IwUI API is going to continue shipping but as a legacy module, so its unlikely to be developed further.  Marmalade have hinted that they will be pointing us at some OpenSource UI solution but haven't said more than that yet.

Comment: Actually we've faced the same issue with latest version of Marmalade. Marmalade people replied that any previous UI builder can work with latest Version. I like to code in Visual studio so I use a PC. If you are using Mac you can also create UI into PC and use it with XCode.

Answer (score 0):

The Marmalade Studio UI Builder has been removed from the Marmalade SDK.

You can download UI Builder from: https://github.com/marmalade/UI-Builder

More Info: http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/native/art_tools_reference/uibuilder.html